# How can I get Team Foundation Server 2010 to display names insteads of accounts?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We've just upgraded TFS from 2005 to 2010. We've also changed from local accounts to Active Directory domain accounts. Under fields such as "Assigned to" and "Created by" the displayed information now looks like "ab.cd.efgh.com\doej" where we would prefer to see friendly names such as "John Doe" or "Doe, John". How is this done?

Comment: Have you ever being able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, the Active Directory display name is used by TFS 2010 automatically.

(See [here](http://www.edsquared.com/Trackback.aspx?guid=53190f81-5227-4bb4-9aa5-58f48c060052) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286562.aspx) for some discussion of the syncnamechanges feature - this may give you something to search on to learn more about how it works)

I believe you can change the names used in TFS simply by editing the display names on your Active Directory accounts, but this will of course have a global effect that may not be desirable. I'm not sure if there is an alternative option, such as disabling syncnamechnages and reverting to simple text fields for these fields.

Comment: All field types are set to synchronize names automatically. I did not need to change anything. It is this way after installation, but it never showed a correct display name.